# server side rendering in angular app like initial api call at build time

Tags: angular, redux

I want to use some nextjs features in angular applications like SSR and SSG, so that our home page or pages that content does not change frequently will load quickly, for example, suppose I have 4-5 API calls on the home page that should be resolved and prerender at build time.

Comment: `4-5 API calls on the home page that should be resolved and prerender at build time` can you explain this? Resolved at the build time -> building web app doesn't call APIs.

Comment: i am talking about how nextjs SSR work

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarification: afaik **Next.js** is a React framework that can not be used with Angular.

---

**SSR/SSG with Angular**

Take a look at [Angular Prerendering Docs](https://angular.io/guide/prerendering) and [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) That should get you going.

I created a [PoC](https://github.com/yanxch/ssr-test), two years ago (Angular 8 - sorry), that uses Angular Universal.
It fetches Github commits at build time.

In the file `static.paths.ts` I defined the routes that should be pre-rendered:

```
export const ROUTES = [
 '/commits/BioPhoton'
];
```

When running `npm build:prerender` and `npm run server` and then navigate to `http://localhost:4000/commits/BioPhoton` you should see that the server state is embedded in the HTML-Body inside a `<script>` tag and no additional request to Github is made.